# the case of the missing /usr/bin/jexec

Tags: debian, java

I was upgrading a package when I came across the following -

```
$ sudo aptitude install openjdk-9-jre=9~b87-1 openjdk-9-jre-headless=9~b87-1 -y
The following packages will be upgraded: 
  openjdk-9-jre openjdk-9-jre-headless 
2 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 30.9 MB of archives. After unpacking 175 MB will be freed.
Get: 1 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ experimental/main openjdk-9-jre amd64 9~b87-1 [39.4 kB]
Get: 2 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ experimental/main openjdk-9-jre amd64 9~b87-1 [39.4 kB]                                                    
Get: 3 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ experimental/main openjdk-9-jre-headless amd64 9~b87-1 [30.8 MB]                                           
Fetched 30.9 MB in 21min 2s (24.4 kB/s)                                                                                                               
Retrieving bug reports... Done
Parsing Found/Fixed information... Done
Reading changelogs... Done
apt-listchanges: Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
apt-listchanges: Mailing root: apt-listchanges: changelogs for think-debian
(Reading database ... 375935 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-9-jre_9~b87-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-9-jre:amd64 (9~b87-1) over (9~b80-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-9-jre-headless_9~b87-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-9-jre-headless:amd64 (9~b87-1) over (9~b80-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1) ...
Setting up openjdk-9-jre-headless:amd64 (9~b87-1) ...
update-binfmts: warning: /usr/share/binfmts/jar: no executable /usr/bin/jexec found, but continuing anyway as you request
Setting up openjdk-9-jre:amd64 (9~b87-1) ...
Scanning processes...                                                                                                                                 
Scanning linux images...                                                                                                                              
Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.
No services need to be restarted.
No containers need to be restarted.
```

Any ideas which /usr/bin/jexec is missing.

Comment: Is that really missing in the end? I've seen installs with scary error messages, resulting from installations more geared to updates (i.e., they assume some pieces are available from the old package). Just a sort-of-wild guess...